# How to read file using ObjectInputStream and add objects to HashSet?

Tags: java, set, objectinputstream

I am trying to read file and add all objects into HashSet but I have an error "User cannot be cast to java.util.HashSet". How can I fix it?

```
private void readFromFile(String file){
    Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
    try(FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)){
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);

        users = (HashSet) objectInputStream.readObject();

        System.out.println(users);
        objectInputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And how can I use serialize more than one object into file?
For example(I am using Scanner and trying to input name and surname), when I do it my file has only one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as @Nicholas K mentioned,

because you wrote `User` objects into the stream, then you should read `User` objects after.

And as you said

> When I tried it I had only one object there but my file includes more
>   than three users

You got one object because **you read only one object**.

Calling

`User user = (User) objectInputStream.readObject();`

reads only one user (if exists). Calling `read()` once more and you will get your second object (again, if it exists).

So all you need to do is this:

```
private void readFromFile(String file){
        Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
        try(FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)){
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);

            while (true) {
                User user = (User) objectInputStream.readObject();
                users.add(user);    
            }

        } catch(EOFException e){
            // This exception is raised because the whole file was read.
            // So print the users in the set.

            for (User user : users) {
                System.out.println(user);
            }

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            // Never forget to close the stream after you're done
            if (objectInputStream!=null) {
                objectInputStream.close();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried your answer and I have an error java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC((

Comment: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1601)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
 at registration.Registration.readFromFile(Registration.java:64)
 at registration.Registration.newUser(Registration.java:15)
 at registration.MainUser.main(MainUser.java:19)

Comment: Yes, it came from readObj, when I debugged while loop saw first wrote object and after that error

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the object returned by `objectInputStream.readObject()` to `User` and then add it to the `HashSet`

Change this

```
users = (HashSet) objectInputStream.readObject();  <--- can't cast User to HashSet
```

to the following

```
User user = (User) objectInputStream.readObject();
users.add(user);
```

Comment: When I tried it I had only one object there but my file includes more than three users

Comment: Yes, they were User

Comment: Did you try my solution? If it is failing, what is the exception?

Comment: I input information about users using Scanner that write this info into file after that I    am reading info and add users into HashSet

Comment: I don't understand. Are your users of the same type `User`? Possible to share the file you're trying to read?

Comment: My file after writing looks like Ted@gmail.comt Ted tedt  adfr34111t ted�� sr registration.User        L emailt Ljava/lang/String;L nameSurnameq ~ L passwordq ~ L userNameq ~ xpt asdf@gmail.comt  asdf werwt 123asdzxcsdt vzxf�� sr registration.

Comment: Add it to the question. Why are there special characters in your file? I suspect you aren't even writing to the file correctly, how do you expect to read from it then?

Comment: I write file using ObjectOutputStream and User class implements Serializable

Comment: Then why are there special characters in the file?